# Python analytics (non web based)

Tags: python, analytics

I have published a library that is used in-house. It is not a web based library but it unifies access to several different datasources and provides access in a unified way.

I would like to gather usage statistics of this library - obviously with the proviso that users of the library don't mind these statistics being taken.

Now this is not a web framework or anything similar, but just a bunch of classes and functions .

Obviously the analytics framework must be able to recover from the gathering back end being not available - in fact the usage of the library must preferably be not affected in anyway by data being sent.

Has anybody written anything like this before? Obviously I could knock up one myself, but when presented with questions like this, I always try to find a version of one done already (as they've probably done a better job than I could ever do).

Answer (score 1):

You could do the local logging and an scheduled statistics uploading that would send this log to your server. Ofcourse, the user will have to give his consent, but this is a common practice i guess. 
For this you can use any logging facility, like  [python.logging](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html).
For uploading to your server you can use any networking library, like [twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/).

These two combined give you an almost complete solution, you just have to do some glue logic.

If you want to do it live, while the library is being used (which I am not sure why would you want), you can still use twisted since it has the ability to do asynchronous transfers.

Comment: Yes obviously twisted is an ideal async framework in which to build this. I am considering a handful of decorators which I'll place on the most interesting functions. I don't want to create a whole new logger as some of the users want to control their own logging. However, still looking for someone who has done this before....

Answer (score 1):

You can use many 'web' analytics platforms inside of desktop or mobile apps.

Mixpanel is a popular one that I have looked at, but you can use google analytics in this way as well. You basically just will have method calls in your code that call out to the mixpanel server whenever you want to log an event.

It will be easier to use one of these vs inventing your own.

Comment: The usage of the library is done internally; ie there is no internet access from the majority of the machines. Also... it would not be a good idea to pass this information to a 3rd party. Saying that, I will look at a few of them for ideas anyway to see if I can migrate it all in house.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay to send data out-of-house, here are two solutions with Python support:

1. Segment
2. Google Analytics

### Segment

[Segment](https://segment.com) seems to be a service that aggregates analytics data and let's you send it on to multiple analytics end points.

The [Python API](https://segment.com/docs/sources/server/python/) for it is open source and easy to use.

- One could change the server URL easily.
- **The library is more sophisticated than Google Analytics!** In particular, the Segment library uses a queue of events and consumes them in a separate thread. If the connection is blocked/slow this will not slow down the application.

Install:

```
$ pip install analytics-python
```

Code:

```
import analytics
analytics.write_key = 'YOUR_WRITE_KEY'
USER_ID = 'some_random_value'

analytics.identify(USER_ID, {
    'email': 'john@example.com',
    'name': 'John Smith',
    'friends': 30
})

def track_function_call(fname, *args, **kwargs):
    analytics.track(USER_ID, 'Function Called', {
        'function_name': fname,
        'args': args, 'kwargs': kwargs
    })

def track_decorator(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        track_function_call(function.__name__, *args, **kwargs)
        return function(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@track_decorator
def main():
    print("My app does nothing but track you.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Google Analytics

Google Analytics provides an [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard/analytics/main.py) in their [tutorial for App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/google-analytics).

It is a crude `requests.post` call, which will block. But the `Consumer` class in Segment's API ([consumer.py](https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-python/blob/master/analytics/consumer.py)) could probably be adopted to `POST` directly to Google Analytics.

```
# From Google's example:
def track_event(category, action, label=None, value=0):
    data = {
        'v': '1',  # API Version.
        'tid': GA_TRACKING_ID,  # Tracking ID / Property ID.
        # Anonymous Client Identifier. Ideally, this should be a UUID that
        # is associated with particular user, device, or browser instance.
        'cid': '555',
        't': 'event',  # Event hit type.
        'ec': category,  # Event category.
        'ea': action,  # Event action.
        'el': label,  # Event label.
        'ev': value,  # Event value, must be an integer
    }

    response = requests.post(
        'http://www.google-analytics.com/collect', data=data)

    # If the request fails, this will raise a RequestException. Depending
    # on your application's needs, this may be a non-error and can be caught
    # by the caller.
    response.raise_for_status()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    track_event(
        category='MyPythonLibrary',
        action='Main called')
    print("My app does nothing.")
```